# How to raise exception in python-pyautoit, if screen not appears within 60 seconds?

Tags: python, robotframework

Following is my python function. I have used "pyautoit" to open a application window. (I wanted to use this function in robot framework as a keyword)

```
def TEST_window():
    autoit.send("#m") # To maximize the screen
    autoit.win_wait_active("[CLASS:TestFrame]", 60) # Wait for 60 secs to window appear
    autoit.send("{ENTER}") # click on ENTER button
```

If expected application window appears within 60 secs, above code is working fine. But I want to raise a exception, if window not appears within 60 secs .

Can anyone guide me on this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`win_wait_active` returns 0 if not succesfull. So it would be something like

```
def TEST_window():
    autoit.send("#m") # To maximize the screen
    if autoit.win_wait_active("[CLASS:TestFrame]", 60) == 0:
        Raise Exception
    else:
        # do your cool stuff here
        autoit.send("{ENTER}") # click on ENTER button
```